# OpenGL Separable shader programs and pipline performance on modern hardware

Tags: c++, c, opengl, glsl, shader

I am porting a small OpenGL framework from 3.3 to 4.3. I have shader mix/match implemented in software (ie: shaders are bound individually and programs are linked lazily when a draw call is issued.).

OpenGL 4.1 added this feature with separable programs & pipelines however the point of having programs encapsulating all the shader stages was to be able to optimize them as a whole (and only once).

So I would like to know if using SPOs is slower than standard shader programs on Direct3D 11 hardware. Especially : do current implementations allow you to have one program per shader (so a pipeline with 2-5 separate programs) without significant performance loss ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is funny you should mention D3D11 hardware by name.

If you talk about D3D, you should know it has always worked this way. Shader programs are not immutable objects with every stage linked together in D3D like they are in OpenGL. D3D uses semantics and other goodies to let you swap out the shader attached to each stage whenever you want. The hardware has always worked the way D3D does and OpenGL just exposes this better now.

Whether you will see a change in performance or not from separable shaders is not a problem with the hardware. Any performance gain or loss will be down to the driver implementation. It cannot be substantial, however, or D3D would have adopted OpenGL's linked program model a long time ago -- that API constantly reinvents itself to lower overhead.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I have never worked with D3D myself, i didn't knew it had separable stage.